# How to print a special string?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a file which has the following content:

```
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 192004  192117  .   +   0   ID=cds185;Parent=gene211;Dbxref=Genbank:WP_013277182.1;Name=WP_013277182.1;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:WP_005487032.1;product=50S ribosomal protein L36;protein_id=WP_013277182.1;transl_table=11
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 1753871 1754437 .   +   0   ID=cds1636;Parent=gene1718;Dbxref=Genbank;Name=NP_013278608.1;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:NP_013278608.1;product=hypothetical protein;protein_id=NP_013278608.1;transl_table=11
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 233759  235705  .   +   0   ID=cds226;Parent=gene252;Dbxref=Genbank;Name=RCSM;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:YP_013277222.1;product=methyl-accepting chemotaxis;transl_table=11
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 486732  488687  .   +   0   ID=cds446;Parent=gene486;Dbxref=Genbank:WP_013277438.1;Name=WP_013277438.1;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:WP_013277438.1;product=methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein;protein_id=WP_013277438.1;transl_table=11
```

I want to get the followin output

```
192004  192117  +  WP_013277182.1
1753871 1754437  +  NP_013278608.1
233759  235705  +  YP_013277222.1
486732  488687  +  WP_013277438.1
```

Which unix command will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Using Perl:

```
perl -naE 'say "$F[4] $F[5] $F[7] ", /([NWY]P_.*?);/'
```

- `perl -naE`   for each line, split in fields and...
- `say "$F[4] $F[5] $F[7] ", /([NWY]P_.*?);/` ... and print 4, 5, 7 and regexp

Comment: I wondered a while now why the fifth field is `$F[4]`, researched perl input delimiter defaults etc. just to finally realize perl begins numbering the fields at 0. :)

Comment: To be able to set the output field delimiter more flexibly, change the `$,` variable, e.g. for two spaces (see OP): `perl -naE '$,="  "; say $F[4], $F[5], $F[7], /(WP_.*?);/'`

Comment: @dessert, thank you. That is a good idea. The example presented by OP has a variable output field delimiter, so I did not take it to seriously.

Comment: @dessert, As you probably notice, my solution is in fact almost a copy of yours :)

Comment: Can you explain `/(WP_.*?);/` please? Why doesn’t that match more than just until the first semicolon, and what does the question mark mean?

Comment: @dessert, `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*` meaning match as less as possible.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{print $5,$6,$8,gensub(/.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/,"\\1",1)}'
```

This prints the (whitespace-separated) fields 5, 6, 8 and the first string beginning with “N”, “W” or “Y” followed by “P_” up until the next semicolon from the current line.

If you want a different **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator, change the OFS variable in the BEGIN block, e.g. for two spaces use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="  "}{print $5,$6,$8,gensub(/.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/,"\\1",1)}'
```

If you want aligned values `OFS="\t"` for tab-separated columns is a good choice.

If you can’t use GNU `awk` you can make use of the `match()` and `substr()` functions to replace `gensub()`:

```
awk 'match($0,/[NWY]P_[^;]+/){print $5,$6,$8,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

#### Explanations

- `print $5,$6,$8` – print these fields separated by the OFS
- `gensub(/.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/,"\\1",1)` – on the (default) whole current line, replace `.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*` with what’s saved in group 1 (`"\\1"`), once. `.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*` matches the whole line saving the first string consisting of “N”, “W” or “Y” followed by “P_” and at least one character which is not “;” (`[^;]+`, as regex are greedy this matches everything until the first semicolon) as a group.
- `match($0,/[NWY]P_[^;]+/)` – search `$0` (= the whole line) for the first match of `[NWY]P_[^;]+` (see above) and set the `RSTART` variable to its index and the `RLENGTH` variable to its character count.
- `substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)` – from `$0`, extract the string starting at index `RSTART` with the lenght of `RLENGTH`

#### Example run

```
$ cat YP 
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 192004  192117  .   +   0   ID=cds185;Parent=gene211;Dbxref=Genbank:WP_013277182.1;Name=WP_013277182.1;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:WP_005487032.1;product=50S ribosomal protein L36;protein_id=WP_013277182.1;transl_table=11
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 1753871 1754437 .   +   0   ID=cds1636;Parent=gene1718;Dbxref=Genbank;Name=NP_013278608.1;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:NP_013278608.1;product=hypothetical protein;protein_id=NP_013278608.1;transl_table=11
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 233759  235705  .   +   0   ID=cds226;Parent=gene252;Dbxref=Genbank;Name=RCSM;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:YP_013277222.1;product=methyl-accepting chemotaxis;transl_table=11
NC_014378.1 Protein Homology    CDS 486732  488687  .   +   0   ID=cds446;Parent=gene486;Dbxref=Genbank:WP_013277438.1;Name=WP_013277438.1;gbkey=CDS;inference=COORDINATES: similar to AA sequence:RefSeq:WP_013277438.1;product=methyl-accepting chemotaxis protein;protein_id=WP_013277438.1;transl_table=11
$ <YP awk '{print $5,$6,$8,gensub(/.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/,"\\1",1)}'
192004 192117 + WP_013277182.1
1753871 1754437 + NP_013278608.1
233759 235705 + YP_013277222.1
486732 488687 + WP_013277438.1
```

Comment: very cool! (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have another question in my file there is some other identifier like
WP_013278608.1
NP_02456869.1
YP_01478423.1
 so How can I use that regex?
and can you please explain this:
{print $5,$6,$8,gensub(/.*(WP_[^;]+).*/,"\\1",1)}

Comment: Just a general note; might be more elegant to post one answer, offering mutiple options than splitting up.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Why? In the case of multiple solutions, each should go in an own answer IMO, this way users can vote for them properly and comment on them easily – and it helps avoid overly long posts. If you for some reason can’t use `awk` but use `sed`, you don’t want to vote on `awk`.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, added – indeed, `mawk` and `nawk` don’t have this function.

Comment: In complex, lengthy answers, totally different approaches, sure. In case of parsing out info, rarely the case. Just a summarization of the smartest tricks mostly.

Comment: I edit the question, Please answer now. and please explain 
{print $5,$6,$8,gensub(/.*(WP_[^;]+).*/,"\\1",1)}

Comment: I update my question, Please look at the output that I want.

Comment: Is there any generic metacharacter instead of using [NYP].

Comment: @ArslanTariq If that doesn’t do, please edit your question accordingly. ;) If you actually want any letter + “P_” + any number until semicolon, *say so* in your question. You may also mean any uppercase letter, or any letter from N to Z – there’s just no way to know if you don’t provide this information.

Comment: It works. I think if I use [A-Z] then it is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*CDS //;s/ *\. //;s/ 0.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/\1/'
```

#### Explanations

- `s/.*CDS //` – `s`ubstitute the string “CDS ” and everything (on the currently processed line) before it with nothing – this deletes the beginning of the line
- `s/ *\. //` – substitute zero or more spaces followed by dot followed by space with nothing – this deletes the dot column and its space characters
- `s/ 0.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/\1/` – substitute “ 0” followed by zero or more characters, the string “N”, “W” or “Y” followed by “P_” followed by at least one character which is not a semicolon (saving this string in a group) followed by zero or more characters by the saved string – this takes the end of the line, extracts the first WP string and deleted everything else

#### Example run

```
$ <YP sed -E 's/.*CDS //;s/ *\. //;s/ 0.*([NWY]P_[^;]+).*/\1/'
192004  192117  +  WP_013277182.1
1753871 1754437  +  NP_013278608.1
233759  235705  +  YP_013277222.1
486732  488687  +  WP_013277438.1
```